# Compare two images with PictureBox controls

Tags: c#, image, winforms, comparison, picturebox

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to [this site](http://sfx.thelazy.net/games/screenshot/17321/full/). I am basically trying to implement a way to "compare" two similar images (with different colors, etc). I managed to do this in a not so brilliant way using two PictureBox controls (Winforms) one next to the other, and changing their Size and Location attributes on a MouseMove event.

The result works, but it flickers a lot and it's not really the best way to do it.
Is there a better way to do this, maybe with a WPF or by changing the code in any way? Here it is:

```
private void pbImg1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pbImg2.Image = CropImage(array[1], new Rectangle(pbImg1.Size.Width, 0, totalSize.Width - pbImg1.Size.Width, 240));
        pbImg1.Size = new Size(e.X, pbImg1.Height);
        pbImg2.Location = new Point(pbImg1.Size.Width + pbImg1.Location.X, pbImg2.Location.Y);
        pbImg2.Size = new Size(totalSize.Width - pbImg1.Size.Width, 240);

        lpbImg1Size.Text = pbImg1.Size.ToString();
        lpbImg2Size.Text = pbImg2.Size.ToString();
        lpbImg1Location.Text = pbImg1.Location.ToString();
        lpbImg2Location.Text = pbImg2.Location.ToString();
    }

private void pbImg2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pbImg1.Image = CropImage(array[0], new Rectangle(0, 0, totalSize.Width - pbImg2.Size.Width, 240));
        pbImg1.Size = new Size(pbImg1.Width + e.X, 240);

        lpbImg1Size.Text = pbImg1.Size.ToString();
        lpbImg2Size.Text = pbImg2.Size.ToString();
        lpbImg1Location.Text = pbImg1.Location.ToString();
        lpbImg2Location.Text = pbImg2.Location.ToString();
    }

public Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap source, Rectangle section)
    {
        // An empty bitmap which will hold the cropped image

        //TRY CATCH
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(section.Width, section.Height);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        // Draw the given area (section) of the source image
        // at location 0,0 on the empty bitmap (bmp)
        g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, section, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        return bmp;
    }
```

And here you can see the behavior of the program:
https://gfycat.com/VillainousReadyAmazonparrot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two images *imageLeft, imageRight* with the same size as the picturebox:

```
private int pos = 0; //x coordinate of mouse in picturebox

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(pos == 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.imageRight, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.imageLeft, new Rectangle(0, 0, pos, pictureBox1.Height),
            new Rectangle(0, 0, pos, pictureBox1.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.imageRight, new Rectangle(pos, 0, pictureBox1.Width - pos, pictureBox1.Height),
            new Rectangle(pos, 0, pictureBox1.Width - pos, pictureBox1.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pos = e.X;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: That was way easier than I though. Thanks.